how to call execute sell function in uniswap v3?
I have called function buy and sell with uniswap v3 and transaction is failed. How to call
I use web3py and call to
def sell_token(web3 : Web3 , chain, wallet_address, address_token, token_abi, private_key):    
    wallet_address = web3.to_checksum_address(wallet_address)
    #Router address
    router_address = web3.to_checksum_address(chain['router_address'])
    contract_router = web3.eth.contract(router_address, abi=chain['swap_router_abi'])
    wrapped_address = web3.to_checksum_address(chain['wrapped_address'])
    #Token
    address_token = web3.to_checksum_address(address_token)
    token_router = web3.eth.contract(address=address_token, abi = token_abi)
    TokenInAccount = int(token_router.functions.balanceOf(wallet_address).call())
   
    match chain['short_name']:
        case 'base':
            path = encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [address_token, 1500, wrapped_address])
            from_eoa = True
            commands = '0x000c'
            v3_calldata = encode(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'bytes', 'bool'], [router_address, TokenInAccount,int(TokenInAccount*0.1), path, from_eoa])
            tx = {  
                    'from': wallet_address,
                    'gas': 300000,
                    'chainId': chain['chainId'],
                    'nonce':  web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)+ 1,
                    'value': 0
                    }
    
            swap_txn  = contract_router.functions.execute(commands, [v3_calldata, web3.to_bytes(hexstr='0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')],int(time.time() + 180)).build_transaction(tx)

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        swap_txn, private_key=private_key)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    print(f"{chain['explorer_url']}{Web3.to_hex(tx_hash)}") 

https://basescan.org/address/0xd9c477548b75778774d1f698a4ec1ddda726962c
transaction fail

I have approve token to router
    approve = token_router.functions.approve(router_address, TokenInAccount).build_transaction({
                                                                'from': wallet_address,                                
                                                                'gas': 200000,
                                                                'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)
                                                            })
            signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
                approve, private_key=private_key)
            tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
            print(f"Approved: {web3.to_hex(tx_token)}")

But this still not work

I have updated my code
        case 'base':
            permit2_address = web3.to_checksum_address('0x000000000022D473030F116dDEE9F6B43aC78BA3')
            approve = token_router.functions.approve(permit2_address, TokenInAccount).build_transaction({
                                                                'from': wallet_address,                                
                                                                'gas': 200000,
                                                                'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address)
                                                            })
            signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
                approve, private_key=private_key)
            tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
            print(f"Approved: {web3.to_hex(tx_token)}")
            commands = '0x000c'
            # Sell Token, FEE , WETH
            path = encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [address_token, 10000, wrapped_address])
            from_eoa = True
            v3_calldata = encode(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'bytes', 'bool'], [wallet_address, TokenInAccount,int(TokenInAccount*0.1), path, from_eoa])
            unwrap_data = encode(['address', 'uint256'], [router_address, 0])

            tx = {  
                    'from': wallet_address,
                    'gas': 300000,
                    'chainId': chain['chainId'],
                    'nonce':  web3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address) + 1,
                    'value': 0
                    }
            swap_txn  = contract_router.functions.execute(commands,[v3_calldata, unwrap_data],int(time.time() + 180)).build_transaction(tx)

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        swap_txn, private_key=private_key)
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    print(f"{chain['explorer_url']}{Web3.to_hex(tx_hash)}") 

and still error Maka
https://basescan.org/tx/0xe495afc9e5d2799e767d215142760ef7009f9d102629bee8fe4d9dc4201e2adf
this is txhash failed

The fee looks incorrect, and approval for this contract is a little more complicated. Which two tokens are you trying to swap for, can you post the addresses?

You can find a tutorial here how to use Uniswap 3 from Python.

Think universal router they want to use, rather than v3 router. Call approve on the permit contract passing that brett token, not on the brett contract passing the permit contract. Change fee and check the encoding, will do simple example.

Some initial issues:
The Fee is going to determine the pool that gets computed and no pool with that fee exists.
In the second failed transaction that appears to be the issue, in the first the calldata appears to be malformed.
BRETT: 0x532f27101965dd16442E59d40670FaF5eBB142E4
WETH: 0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006
Fee: 10000

# calling getPool() at the factory returns
address :  0xBA3F945812a83471d709BCe9C3CA699A19FB46f7

This one has the liquidity. 0xBA3F945812a83471d709BCe9C3CA699A19FB46f7
So the path should be
FEE = 10000

# (address tokenIn, uint24 fee, address tokenOut)
path = encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [BRETT_ADDRESS, FEE, WETH_ADDRESS])

If swapping from something other than native coin, it does need approval and with universal router it seems a bit more involved.
You do need to grant the permit contract an allowance to move your tokens (which you had already done), but (to clarify my comment above) following that you need to call approve on the permit contract passing the token and router (or sign and include a signature which is a little more advanced).
Theoretically it is safe to grant max amount as it is a relatively simple, thoroughly audited contract, with the idea being that you grant approvals to the permit contract, rather than the myriad of dapps you use, and then grant the dapp to be the receiver of the tokens when needed.
So we want to :

call approve on the token contract passing the permit address and max amount to grant dapps to utilise when permitted.

call approve on the permit contract passing the token address, router as spender, max amount to grant to the router till the deadline, and the deadline.

construct and send the swap data.


As in your example that got furthest, using commands:
0x000c # v3 swap and unwrap.

And fee/path above.
Example:
from web3 import Web3; w3 = Web3(Provider('...'))
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
eoa = w3.eth.account.from_key(getenv('TKEY'))
#----------------------

PERMIT_ADDRESS  = '0x000000000022D473030F116dDEE9F6B43aC78BA3'
BRETT_ADDRESS   = '0x532f27101965dd16442E59d40670FaF5eBB142E4'
WETH_ADDRESS    = '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619'
ROUTER_ADDRESS  = '0x198EF79F1F515F02dFE9e3115eD9fC07183f02fC'

ROUTER_ABI = '''
[{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"permit2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"weth9","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaportV1_5","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"seaportV1_4","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"openseaConduit","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"nftxZap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"x2y2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"foundation","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"sudoswap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"elementMarket","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"nft20Zap","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"cryptopunks","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareV2","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"routerRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareRewardsDistributor","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"looksRareToken","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v2Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"v3Factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"pairInitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"poolInitCodeHash","type":"bytes32"}],"internalType":"struct RouterParameters","name":"params","type":"tuple"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BalanceTooLow","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BuyPunkFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ContractLocked","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ETHNotAccepted","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandIndex","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"message","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExecutionFailed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"FromAddressIsNotOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientETH","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InsufficientToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidBips","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"commandType","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InvalidCommandType","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC1155","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidOwnerERC721","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidReserves","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSpender","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"LengthMismatch","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"SliceOutOfBounds","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransactionDeadlinePassed","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnableToClaim","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"UnsafeCast","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2InvalidPath","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V2TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidAmountOut","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3InvalidSwap","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooLittleReceived","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"V3TooMuchRequested","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsSent","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"looksRareClaim","type":"bytes"}],"name":"collectRewards","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"commands","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes[]","name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155BatchReceived","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC1155Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onERC721Received","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"","type":"bytes4"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1Delta","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"uniswapV3SwapCallback","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]
'''
PERMIT_ABI = '''
[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"AllowanceExpired","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ExcessiveInvalidation","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InsufficientAllowance","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"InvalidAmount","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidContractSignature","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidNonce","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSignature","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSignatureLength","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"InvalidSigner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"LengthMismatch","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"signatureDeadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"SignatureExpired","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint48","name":"expiration","type":"uint48"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"Lockdown","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint48","name":"newNonce","type":"uint48"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint48","name":"oldNonce","type":"uint48"}],"name":"NonceInvalidation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint48","name":"expiration","type":"uint48"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint48","name":"nonce","type":"uint48"}],"name":"Permit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"word","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"mask","type":"uint256"}],"name":"UnorderedNonceInvalidation","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_SEPARATOR","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"expiration","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"nonce","type":"uint48"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"expiration","type":"uint48"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"newNonce","type":"uint48"}],"name":"invalidateNonces","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wordPos","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"mask","type":"uint256"}],"name":"invalidateUnorderedNonces","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"internalType":"struct IAllowanceTransfer.TokenSpenderPair[]","name":"approvals","type":"tuple[]"}],"name":"lockdown","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"nonceBitmap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"expiration","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"nonce","type":"uint48"}],"internalType":"struct IAllowanceTransfer.PermitDetails[]","name":"details","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"sigDeadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IAllowanceTransfer.PermitBatch","name":"permitBatch","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"permit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"expiration","type":"uint48"},{"internalType":"uint48","name":"nonce","type":"uint48"}],"internalType":"struct IAllowanceTransfer.PermitDetails","name":"details","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"sigDeadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct IAllowanceTransfer.PermitSingle","name":"permitSingle","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"permit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.TokenPermissions","name":"permitted","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.PermitTransferFrom","name":"permit","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"requestedAmount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.SignatureTransferDetails","name":"transferDetails","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"permitTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.TokenPermissions[]","name":"permitted","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.PermitBatchTransferFrom","name":"permit","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"requestedAmount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.SignatureTransferDetails[]","name":"transferDetails","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"permitTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.TokenPermissions","name":"permitted","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.PermitTransferFrom","name":"permit","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"requestedAmount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.SignatureTransferDetails","name":"transferDetails","type":"tuple"},{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"witness","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"string","name":"witnessTypeString","type":"string"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"permitWitnessTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.TokenPermissions[]","name":"permitted","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.PermitBatchTransferFrom","name":"permit","type":"tuple"},{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"requestedAmount","type":"uint256"}],"internalType":"struct ISignatureTransfer.SignatureTransferDetails[]","name":"transferDetails","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"witness","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"string","name":"witnessTypeString","type":"string"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"signature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"permitWitnessTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"}],"internalType":"struct IAllowanceTransfer.AllowanceTransferDetails[]","name":"transferDetails","type":"tuple[]"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"amount","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
'''
ERC20_ABI = '''
[{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawal","type":"event"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"guy","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"src","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"dst","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
'''
router = w3.eth.contract(address=ROUTER_ADDRESS, abi=ROUTER_ABI)
permit = w3.eth.contract(address=PERMIT_ADDRESS, abi=PERMIT_ABI)
token  = w3.eth.contract(address=BRETT_ADDRESS,  abi=ERC20_ABI )

tx = {
        'from': eoa.address,
        'value': 0,
        'chainId': w3.eth.chain_id,
        'gas': 250000,
        'maxFeePerGas': w3.eth.gas_price * 2,
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.eth.max_priority_fee*2,
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(eoa.address)
}
#---------------------------------------------------------------
#  https://github.com/Uniswap/universal-router/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Commands.sol
#    uint256 constant V3_SWAP_EXACT_IN = 0x00;
#    uint256 constant UNWRAP_WETH = 0x0c;
# ----

# we will swap on v3 then unwrap the native token

commands = '0x000c'

from eth_abi import encode
from eth_abi.packed import encode_packed
# some sane inputs (sane doesn't mean safe in this case, always use a good slippage value unless protected some other way)
to = ROUTER_ADDRESS  # router from swap, then our address from unwrap
amount = 1 * 10 ** 4
slippage = 0
FEE = 10000
path = encode_packed(['address','uint24','address'], [BRETT_ADDRESS, FEE, WETH_ADDRESS])
from_eoa = True
unwrap_calldata = encode(['address', 'uint256'], [eoa.address, slippage])
v3_calldata = encode(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'bytes', 'bool'], [to, amount, slippage, path, from_eoa])
deadline = 2*10**10

# PERMIT
# permit is a little involved, there are two ways you can do it. In both cases it is necessary to first perform
# a `classical` approval for the permit2 contract to move your tokens, as it is that contracts allowance that will be spent.
# this approval needs to be performed in a preceding transaction (unless as part of an atomic call from as custom contract for example)
# Following that approval we have two options we can explicitly "approve" the router as a spender of the permit2 contracts allowance in another transaction/call. # The benefit of this method is that the process is intuitive and familiar, it can be performed via a block explorer without any special encoding or signing.
# A second approach is to sign permit data (A set of encoded values), and send the signature for that permit along with the swap.
# While this method increases complexity a little it removes the need for the additional transaction to the permit2 contract to grant a approval to the router.

# We will keep it simple for this example:
approve_permit = token.functions.approve(PERMIT_ADDRESS, amount)
approve_router = permit.functions.approve(BRETT_ADDRESS, ROUTER_ADDRESS, amount, deadline)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def sign_tx(tx, key):
  sig = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction
  signed_tx = sig(tx, private_key=key)
  return signed_tx

def send_tx(signed_tx):
  w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
  tx_hash = w3.to_hex(w3.keccak(signed_tx.rawTransaction))
  return tx_hash

def main():

  approve1 = approve_permit.build_transaction(tx)
  print ('[-] Approving permit... ')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(approve1, eoa.key))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[+] Approved PERMIT2 at TOKEN contract: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

  tx.update({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(eoa.address)})

  approve2 = approve_router.build_transaction(tx)
  print ('[-] Approving router... ')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(approve2, eoa.key))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[+] Approved ROUTER at PERMIT contract: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

  tx.update({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(eoa.address)})

  swap = router.functions.execute(commands, [v3_calldata,unwrap_calldata], deadline).build_transaction(tx)
  print(swap)
  print('[-] Simulating swap...')
  w3.eth.call(swap)
  print('[-] Attempting swap...')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(swap, eoa.key))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[>] Hash of swap: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()


Added note:
When using a fork to simulate the correct approval for permit, then using your latest failed calldata it gets all the way to (amountOut < amountOutMinimum) revert V3TooLittleReceived()
Be sure to account for any tax subtracting that from the minimum output amount, and to make sure the amountOutMin is not too tight for other organic swaps to land before yours.
